# What's the proper antique equivalent to "Don't you dare"?

Tags: early-modern-english, thou-thee-thy

What's the proper antique (using "thee") equivalent to "Don't you dare"? Dare thee not? Dare not thee? Something else?

Comment: Shouldn't it be *thou*?

Comment: Was thinking it would be similar to "Fare thee well", for which see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222733/fare-thee-well-grammar?rq=1

Comment: I’m thinking it would be along the lines of “Thou wouldst not dare”

Comment: @OrbitalAussie No, *thee* is in object case, like *me*. Subject case is *thou* .

Comment: @tchrist. Thank you, I was over my depth here. My reading of the dictionary entry was too simplistic.

Comment: Depending on whether you consider the second person singular of "do" to be "doest" or "dost" - the answer surely is "Dost thou not dare!" or "Doest not thou dare!". Problem is "don't you dare" has an idiomatic quality about it, which is difficult to replace in the little-used singular.

Comment: *darest thou to ...*

Comment: Umm, *antique*? :)

Comment: Antique? As used in Antique shops? And why “proper”? Is this to discourage vulgar remarks. The question is meaningless without the specification of a particular historical period. And when posting a question here you need to explain what research you have done to answer it yourself.

Comment: @Orbital Aussi: that's not *how dare thee*, that's *how dare ye*. For Middle English pronouns, *ye* was the second person plural corresponding to *thou* in the singular.

Comment: @PeterShor. Thanks. Yes, I can see that now. I’ll delete my comment now that both points have been disproven!

Comment: I meant `archaic` but somehow typed 'antique` instead. I couldn't find anything about where the 'not' should go. Looking at 'thee' vs. 'thou' leads to all sorts of confusing and contradictory advice. The context is I'm re-writing the Canadian national anthem as one the US air-traffic-controllers might sing, alluding to the Air Canada near miss. (See e.g https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Canada_Flight_759). So something like "Air Canada! Dost thou not dare to land!" might work. (Since the song already uses "thee" and I want to be consistent with that.)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/615016/2085).

Answer (score 5):

In Shakespearean usage, *thou* was the nominative, and *thee* was the objective. This needs to be the nominative. Further, the imperative conjugation for *thou* was *do, dare*, and the indicative was *dost, darest*. So you would have to use *do* or *dare*.

So it would have been one of

> Dare thou not,
>   Dare not thou,
>   Do not thou dare.

The position of *not* was flexible in Shakespeare in the imperative, so I believe all of these work. Use whichever of them you think sounds best. From Shakespeare, we have:

> We will have vengeance for it, fear thou not.
>   Come not thou near me.
>   Do not you meddle; let me deal in this.

(I couldn't find a case where Shakespeare used *thou* in the third construction, but for Shakespeare, *you* and *thou* would have worked in the same way.)